# Erro ao utilizar framework JPlay para jogos!

Tags: java, eclipse, 2d

Olá, eu estou tentando programar em java com a framework JPlay, e estou encontrando um erro que era inexistente em um outro pc que eu tinha. O passo que da erro se encontra nessa video aula: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntDvADUoMs8

codigo da classe jogo:

```
package jogo;

import jplay.GameImage;
import jplay.URL;
import jplay.Window;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Window janela = new Window(800,600);
     GameImage plano = new GameImage(URL.sprite("menu.png"));

     while(true){
         plano.draw();
         janela.update();    
     }
 } }
```

O erro é a imagem de fundo que não renderiza. Estou usando a versão 1.8 do java. Espero que os amigos me possam ajudar a solucionar este probleminha da "tela cinza".

Answer (score 0):

Cara passei pela mesma situação e a solução é muito simples...

Em vez de vs fazer:

```
GameImage plano = new GameImage(URL.sprite("menu.png"));
```

vs deve passar o caminho direto da imagem, que no seu caso seria ***"src/recursos/sprites/menu.png"***.. Ficando deste jeito:

```
GameImage plano = new GameImage("src/recursos/sprites/menu.png");
```

Vs precisa fazer isto também para os arquivos de tiles e os arquivos de cenário scn, ou seja, não use a classe URL e use o caminho direto do arquivo que vs quer usar para não dar erro.

Carregar arquivo de cenário:

```
cena.loadFromFile("src/recursos/cenarios/Cenario1.scn")
```

Para carregar os arquivos de tiles é só colocar o caminho completo dele no arquivo de cenario.

Cara se fizer direitinho, não vai dar erro.
Tomara que dê tudo certo! :D